# Time Complexity of a multidimentional array (when cutting to quarter each time)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, matrix

we got a matrix size of NxN which is represented by a multidimentional array, the matrix contains integer numbers, **we assume that N=2^K**.
We can also say that the matrix is **ordered** by cutting the matrix to 4 quarters (image below), every element in the first quarter is smaller or equal to the element in the second quarter, every element in the second quarter is smaller or equal to the third quarter, and every element in the third quarter is smaller or equal to every element in the forth quarter. **(and so on recursivly)**

like this:

```
1 2
3 4
```

Example of sorted matrix:

[image]

We need to write a function that returns true if the num exist in the matrix.
and to make it as most efficient as possible.

I've wrote the following function:

```
public static boolean isExist(int[][] mat, int num)
{
    int start_rows = 0; 
    int start_columns = 0; 

    // If more then 4 elements
    // Loop log(base 4)n
    for (int elements_size = mat.length * mat[0].length, table_size, quarter_size,
            quarter1, quarter2, quarter3, quarter4; 
            (elements_size > 4); 
            elements_size /= 4) 
    {
        table_size = (int)(Math.sqrt(elements_size));
        quarter1 = mat[start_rows+(table_size/2)-1][start_columns+(table_size/2)-1];
        quarter2 = mat[start_rows+(table_size/2)-1][start_columns+table_size-1];
        quarter3 = mat[start_rows+table_size-1][start_columns+(table_size/2)-1];
        quarter4 = mat[start_rows+table_size-1][start_columns+table_size-1];

        if (num == quarter1 || num == quarter2 || num == quarter3 || num == quarter4) {
            return true;
        }

        // Decrease elements_size
        quarter_size = (int)Math.sqrt(elements_size/4);

        if (quarter1 > num) {
            // Dont do anything
        } else if (quarter2 > num) {
            start_columns += quarter_size;  // Increase columns
        } else if (quarter3 > num) {
            start_rows += quarter_size; // Increase rows
        } else if (quarter4 > num) {
            start_rows += quarter_size; // Increase rows
            start_columns += quarter_size; // Increase columns
        } else {
            return false; // bigger then quarter, fail.
        }
    }

    return (mat[start_rows][start_columns] == num || mat[start_rows+1][start_columns] == num || 
            mat[start_rows][start_columns+1] == num || mat[start_rows+1][start_columns+1] == num);
}
```

Is that the most efficient way to do so?
Also its time complexity is O(logn). (am I correct?)

Comment: I haven't checked for correctness, but yes the complexity of this algorithm is O(logN). Proof: 4^k = N^2. Hence k ~ logN. Since we cannot do better than O(logN), we can assume that this is the most efficient way to search.

Answer (score 1):

well, that is a good approach!
if i understood you right, you want to find out if the array includes a specific int-value;
well, i would use the following methode (but you have to match this to a int [][] array):

```
HashSet<Integer> test= new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(intArray));
test.contains(intValue)
```

*this approach is pretty fastest because the hashcode-mechanism has the complexity O(1)  but i think through the asList()-  it leads to arraylist complexity O(n)... not sure about this!!*

Comment: I cannot use HashSet, also its very good to know. its an excersize from the University.
Just wondering If I done it right and its O(logN) complexity/

Comment: oh, i see- well,your code looks like a good solution! as  the user "Abhishek Bansal" commented on your post , it should be O(logN)!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in time complexity O(n). I am not sure if the post is still active. But below is my solution to do it in O(n).

```
public class NumberInMatrix {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int matrix[][] = {{-4,-2,5,9},
                          {2,5,12,13},
                          {13,20,25,25},
                          {22,24,49,57},};
        System.out.println(isExist(matrix, 1));
    }

private static String isExist(int[][] matrix, int numberToBeSearched) {
    int rowCounter = 0, colCounter = matrix[0].length - 1;
    while(rowCounter < matrix.length && colCounter >= 0){
        if(numberToBeSearched == matrix[rowCounter][colCounter]){
            return "Number exist";
        }else{
            if(numberToBeSearched > matrix[rowCounter][colCounter]){
                rowCounter++;
            }else{
                colCounter--;
            }
        }
    }
    return "Number does not exist";
}
```

}